# c# share reference between collection item and properties

Tags: c#, wpf, ref

i'm facing the following issue

in my (C#/WPF) application
[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nF4u.png)

i build an itemsControl that display a collection of UserControl which themselves contain, among other, a dataGrid.
i'm using the following code structure:

```cs
 // define the content of ItemsControl
public class ICContent
{
    public BindingList<bool> AllRowsVisibility { get; set; }
    public BindingList<UCContent> UCContentList { get; set; }
}

// define the content of 1 UserControl
public class UCContent
{
    public string GeneralStuff { get; set; }
    public BindingList<AllRowsDetails> RowDetails { get; set; }

}

// define all the datagrid rows for each UserControl
public class AllRowsDetails
{
    // IsRowVisible is use in the dataBinding to collapse/display the row
    public bool IsRowVisible { get; set; }
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    public string ColumnB { get; set; }
}
```

all the dataGrid rows must be able to be filtered. to do that i use AllRowsDetails.IsRowVisible to trigger the collapse/visible property for each rows.

the problem is that if i set AllRowsDetails.IsRowVisible for each rows of each UserControl datagrid, the calculation take too much time.

So, i calculate ICContent.AllRowsVisibility one time,
and i want the ICContent.AllRowsVisibility elements and AllRowsDetails.IsRowVisible elements share the same reference.

in this way:
UCContentList[i].rowDetails[j].IsRowVisible = AllRowsVisibility[j]

and every time AllRowsVisibility[j] change, UCContentList[i].RowDetails[j].IsRowVisible change too

but i don't know how different elements can share the same ref?

Comment: Can you use the [ref keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)?

Comment: First thing to fix: start following .NET naming conventions. All your properties should start with capital letters. It may seem unimportant, but you really want to reduce any sort of distraction when you're looking through code.

Comment: i don't know if the "ref keyword" can make différents properties to point to the same reference?

Comment: Rows don't need to know about are they visible or not. Instead you can change collection with filtered collection of rows which will update view with only rows in the filtered collection

Comment: @Fabio, i set up your solution, it's pretty fast, the only little problem after update my BindingList, by this way : UCContentList[i].RowDetails = new BindingList<UCContent>(MyLinqResult), i have to manually update the Datacontext. Anyway, thanks a lot, your solution is effective.

Comment: If you will use "viewmodel" as DataContext, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and which have property `Details` where setter will raise `PropertyChanged` every time new collection is given. Then will be enough set : `viewmodel.Details = new BindingList<UCContent>(MyLinqResult)` to update control with filtered rows

Comment: @Fabio, i got `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on all my Class (not in this code sample, but in my real code, i got it). if i do `viewmodel.Details = new BindingList<UCContent>(MyLinqResult)` i don't raise any event, but if i clear Details : `viewmodel.Details.Clear()` for example i raise an event !!! There is something I do not understand

Comment: `viewmodel.Details.Clear()` updates control because `BindingList` raises `ListChanged` event and controls listening for that. For new instance of `BindingList` you need to add line which raise it "manually" in setter of `Details` after local variable set to the new value. `_localDetails = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Details));`

Comment: @Fabio, i thought falsely that `BindingList` natively raise event for new instance. you're a c# sensei. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I set up the @Fabio solution:

i build the class that describe my ItemsControl

```
   // define the content of ItemsControl
    public class ICContent
    {
        public BindingList<UCContent> UCContentList { get; set; }
    }

    // define the content of 1 UserControl
    public class UCContent
    {
        public string GeneralStuff { get; set; }
        public BindingList<AllRowsDetails> RowDetails { get; set; }
    }

    // define all the datagrid rows for each UserControl
    public class AllRowsDetails
    {
        public string CodeClient { get; set; }
        public string columnA { get; set; }
        public string columnB { get; set; }
    }
```

i instanciate two ICContent objects

```
public class Init
{
    public ICContent AllUCContentList { get; set; }
    public ICContent ToDisplayUCContentList { get; set; }

    public Init()
    {
        // original object 
        AllUCContentList = new ICContent();
        // object dedicated to the display
        ToDisplayUCContentList = new ICContent();
    }
}
```

And in my codeBehind i add a new event handler to the changing selected filter event:

```
    private void changeDisplayToSelectedClient(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Wait);

        if (MainWindow.theSelectedClient[0] != null)
        {
            for (int uc = 1; uc < ToDisplayUCContentList.Count; uc++)
            {
                List<AllRowsDetails> theFilteredList = (from item in AllUCContentList[uc].RowDetails
                                       where item.codeClient == MainWindow.theSelectedClient[0].Code
                                       select item).ToList();

                ToDisplayUCContentList[uc].RowDetails = new BindingList<AllRowsDetails>(theFilteredList);
            }
        }
    }
```

it works well, and it's pretty fast.

Thanks @Fabio